# How to configure non existing deployment target to Octopus Deploy?

Tags: release, release-management, octopus-deploy

I am trying to create a release in Octopus to deploy my app while creating it at the runtime. Octopus is not allowing me to proceed without deployment target.
Please someone let me know how to configure my release with no deployment target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached link has the detailed step-by-step guide to dynamic infrastructure implementation.
https://octopus.com/blog/dynamic-infrastructure